Metadata Locks in MySQL while adding Foreign key constraint using ALTER TABLE command
I am running MySQL RDS v8 with 8vCPU & 64Gigs RAM i.e db.m5.4xlarge. I have a table A with primary key on column "id" which is an auto increment and is using BigInt as data type. The table has a total number of 33.5k rows with a total size of 550MB and the index size is 16.5MB.
I am creating a new table B with a column product_id which is a foreign key on the table A. The alter table command to create foreign key is waiting for metadata locks, while other queries that are only of type SELECT are running but those could not start execution as all the other queries also waits for metadata locks. Queries that does not have anything to do with any of the table A or B also keeps waiting for metadata locks.
I don't understand why is this happening?
I far as I know, SELECT statements doesn't gets affected by Alter table commands, specially when the alter command is to add a foreign key.
There are no concurrent DDL commands running on both A or B and, I have already indexed the column to be indexed in table B, so that i just have to create a foreign key.
Foreign key checks shouldn't come in action as the table B is empty.
I have also tried running the alter table command  in a transaction with an isolation level set to READ COMMITTED but that didn't worked either.
Also think that there cannot be any existing locks on table A, since, it is purely used for only SELECT statements. There are zero update or inserts or alter table command on table A.

ALTER TABLE does require an exclusive metadata lock, even if the operation is brief and even if it's metadata-only.
A SELECT statement does not acquire row locks, but it does acquire a shared metadata lock until the transaction is done. It doesn't matter what the transaction isolation level is.
Likewise, since an ALTER TABLE is waiting for an exclusive metadata lock, other queries queue up behind it, waiting. Even though they are read-only queries.
The solution in your case is to finish any transactions that have queried either the parent or child table, even if they are read-only queries, and even if they examined no rows.
Then the ALTER TABLE will get its metadata lock, complete its change, and release the metadata lock so other queries that are queued behind it can do their work.

Demonstration:
In one window, I create a small table and query it in a transaction. I don't commit the transaction yet.
mysql> create table parent (id int primary key);

mysql> begin;

mysql> select * from parent;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

In a second window, I try to execute an ALTER TABLE that should be metadata-only. It hangs, waiting.
mysql> alter table parent comment 'comment';
<hangs>

We see in the processlist that it is waiting.
mysql> show processlist;
+----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Id | User            | Host      | db   | Command | Time   | State                           | Info                                 |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 11 | root            | localhost | test | Query   |      0 | init                            | show processlist                     |
| 12 | root            | localhost | test | Query   |    319 | Waiting for table metadata lock | alter table parent comment 'comment' |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+

The same behavior affects any ALTER TABLE. For example, if the transaction that read parent is still uncommitted, then adding a foreign key to a child table waits for a metadata lock on both parent and child tables.
mysql> show processlist;
+----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User            | Host      | db   | Command | Time   | State                           | Info                                                                |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 11 | root            | localhost | test | Query   |      0 | init                            | show processlist                                                    |
| 12 | root            | localhost | test | Query   |      2 | Waiting for table metadata lock | alter table child add foreign key (parent_id) references parent(id) |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+

In either case, if I COMMIT in the first window, I see the ALTER TABLE finally completes (in this case after 2 min 25 sec).
mysql> alter table child add foreign key (parent_id) references parent(id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (2 min 25.92 sec)


I would add the link to the relevant secttion of mysql manual, as much of the question and the answer could have been avoided by the OP reading it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/metadata-locking.html

Thanks for this explanation Bill. I had spent last few hours only reading about this and kind of figured out what's happening & your answer made it much more clear. I've a read heavy system that also leverages transactions. It is highly possible that whenever I run an ALTER TABLE, there would be thousands of transactions that are open, causing the ALTER TABLE to wait for MDL and piling up queries sent to DB after ALTER TABLE.  Any idea how can i avoid this problem?

As I wrote above, the only solution is to finish your transactions. That's the only way a metadata lock will be available for the ALTER TABLE.
